# How to insert noatime in /etc/fstab CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos7, fstab

this is my /etc/fstab file:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2   /   ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0    0   0
```

How to enable noatime? I do not know exactly where to insert the string.
I think that is:

```
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

That´s right? or Is in dev/md/2?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work. But it makes more sense to delete the `defaults` placeholder when you add it:

```
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 noatime 0 0
```

You probably care more about adding that mount option to slash, though:

```
/dev/md/2   /   ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0,noatime    0   0
```

Comment: Thank you J H. I want to configure my server for works with SSD. I have SSD in RAID 1, then... What´s the best option?

Comment: `noatime` is orthogonal to drive type. The man page *does* comment on the usefulness of the `discard` option in an SSD environment - YMMV.